# Determining Subtraction Overflow with C code

Tags: c, overflow

```
#include <stdio.h>

int tsub_ok(int x, int y);

int tsub_ok(int x,int y)
{
    int dif = 0; //The difference of our two numbers.
    dif = x - y; //X is the minuhend. Y is the subtrahend.
    printf("DIFFERENCE: %d\n", dif); //Output difference.

    if ((x >= 0 && y < 0) || (x < 0 && y >= 0)) { //IF THE SIGNS ARE DIFFERENT (they have to be)
        if (x >= 0 && y < 0 && dif < 0) { //MINUHEND IS POSITIVE, SUBTRAHEND IS NEGATIVE, AND DIFFERENCE IS NEGATIVE. (OVERFLOW OCCURS)
            printf("OVERFLOW\n");
            return 0;
        }
        else if (x < 0 && y >= 0 && dif >= 0) { // MINUHEND IS NEGATIVE, SUBTRAHEND IS POSITIVE, DIFFERENCE IS POSITIVE. (OVERFLOW OCCURS)
            printf("OVERFLOW\n");
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            printf("No Overflow!!\n"); //Overflow does NOT occur in any other condition.
            return 1;
        }
    } 
    else { //IN ANY OTHER CONDITION, THERE IS NO OVERFLOW.
        printf("No Overflow!!\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

int main() {
    int x, y;

    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
    int ans = tsub_ok(x, y);
    printf("%d\n", ans);

    return 0; 
}
```

**NB: Investigating integer arithmetic for signed 4 bit values**

I have this code to determine if subtraction overflow occurs. But when I input 7 and -6, numbers that should overflow when subtraction occurs between them, I get the opposite result. Is this because of how I calculate the "dif" variable? Should it be y - x? Or is my code incorrect?

Because I know if you subtract -6 from 7, overflow is supposed to occur. But regardless if I enter -6 and then 7, or 7 and then -6, my program claims that no overflow occurred.

*EDIT* I forgot to provide the image for context. This is what I mean by overflow, and it has the subtracting - 6 from 7 example. I merely want my code to emulate the example shown in the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Why would overflow occur? `7 - -6` is the same as `7 + 6`. That's not big enough to overflow.

Comment: How exactly would you define "overflow"?  I suspect it's not how others use that term.

Comment: Your example uses 4 bit numbers.  An `int` is 32 bit, so you need much larger numbers for overflow to occur.

Comment: dif = x - y; is not safe in c for all x and y risking UB (undefined behaviour). e.g. INT_MIN - 1 can't be correctly stored in an int without underflow.

Comment: Please edit your question and explain for all to see that you're using a novel datatype called **signed nibble**, a signed 4 bit integer... Otherwise, this is not obvious to the casual reader and just causes confusion...

Comment: *"I merely want my code to emulate the example shown in the screenshot"* you can't because you don't have a 4 bit datatype.  You need to work with larger numbers.

Comment: @dbush Then again, there's BCD...

Comment: C23 will have standard support for "checked" addition/subtraction/multiplication. But no compiler lib seems to support stdckdint.h just yet.

Answer (score 3):

**Avoid overflow**

Early in the function is `dif = x - y;`, which may overflow, causing *undefined behavior* (UB) and render the rest of code moot.
Remove that line of code.

Instead compare the sign and against the limits of the type: `INT_MIN, INT_MAX`.

[Simple tests](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/93699/29485) for `+,-,*,/`

```
#include <limits.h>

int tsub_ok(int x, int y) {
  if ((y < 0) ? (x > INT_MAX + y) : (x < INT_MIN + y)) {
    printf("OVERFLOW\n");
    return 0;    
  } 
  printf("No Overflow!!\n");
  return 1;    
}
```

---

Even if limited to values -8 to 7, code is relying on `x - y` being valid.  The potential subtraction results are [-15 to 15], which needs 5 bits (`int5_t`) to represent.  That is well inside the range of `int`.

Yet if the lesson here is then applied to a full range `int`, then `int dif = x - y;`, code breaks down as `x - y` is not well defined as it needs 1 wider bit math to encode all possible outcomes.

To well prevent overflow in `int` subtraction, we need to first perform tests that they themselves do not overflow.

In `C`, one cannot detect full range integer overflow *after* the fact using `x - y` without resorting to wider math.

We could use the below to extend the general concept to any `N` bit width (within `int`) for 2's complement integer types.

```
#define N 4
#define MY_MAX (((1 << (N - 2)) - 1)*2 + 1)
#define MY_MIN (-MY_MAX - 1) 
if ((b < 0) ? (a > MY_MAX + b) : (a < MY_MIN + b)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Without solving your assignment, there's the following for you to work from:

```
int tsub_ok( int x, int y ) {
    int dif = x - y;
    printf( "%d- (%d) :: %1X - %1X = %1X  /  ", x, y, x & 0xF, y & 0xF, dif & 0xF );

    return 1;
}

int main( void ) {
    int y = -6;

    for( int x = 7; x > 0; x-- ) {
        for( int y = -6; y < 0; y++ )
            tsub_ok( x, y );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
7- (-6) :: 7 - A = D  /  7- (-5) :: 7 - B = C  /  7- (-4) :: 7 - C = B  /  7- (-3) :: 7 - D = A  /  7- (-2) :: 7 - E = 9  /  7- (-1) :: 7 - F = 8  /
6- (-6) :: 6 - A = C  /  6- (-5) :: 6 - B = B  /  6- (-4) :: 6 - C = A  /  6- (-3) :: 6 - D = 9  /  6- (-2) :: 6 - E = 8  /  6- (-1) :: 6 - F = 7  /
5- (-6) :: 5 - A = B  /  5- (-5) :: 5 - B = A  /  5- (-4) :: 5 - C = 9  /  5- (-3) :: 5 - D = 8  /  5- (-2) :: 5 - E = 7  /  5- (-1) :: 5 - F = 6  /
4- (-6) :: 4 - A = A  /  4- (-5) :: 4 - B = 9  /  4- (-4) :: 4 - C = 8  /  4- (-3) :: 4 - D = 7  /  4- (-2) :: 4 - E = 6  /  4- (-1) :: 4 - F = 5  /
3- (-6) :: 3 - A = 9  /  3- (-5) :: 3 - B = 8  /  3- (-4) :: 3 - C = 7  /  3- (-3) :: 3 - D = 6  /  3- (-2) :: 3 - E = 5  /  3- (-1) :: 3 - F = 4  /
2- (-6) :: 2 - A = 8  /  2- (-5) :: 2 - B = 7  /  2- (-4) :: 2 - C = 6  /  2- (-3) :: 2 - D = 5  /  2- (-2) :: 2 - E = 4  /  2- (-1) :: 2 - F = 3  /
1- (-6) :: 1 - A = 7  /  1- (-5) :: 1 - B = 6  /  1- (-4) :: 1 - C = 5  /  1- (-3) :: 1 - D = 4  /  1- (-2) :: 1 - E = 3  /  1- (-1) :: 1 - F = 2  /
```

The two values are shown in decimal, then both again as a single digit hexadecimal. Notice when `dif <= 7` and when `dif > 7`.

Another *bit* of useful thinking (pardon the pun) is `x & 0x8` (testing of b3) to determine if your "sign bit" indicates a positive value, or a negative value.

Take what you know about "two's complement" representations, study the table, and you can work out a test to determine if over-/underflow has occurred.